# Django add a variable value into {%static 'path' %}

Tags: django, python-3.x

In my django project i have to add a prefix into some path defined with %static like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/animate.css" %}">
```

I have to add the {{ subpath }} value passed from my view, i try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "{{ subpath }}/css/animate.css" %}">
```

but the variable was implemented like a text, also i tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static {{ subpath }}"/css/animate.css" %}">
```

but an error occurred.

How can i add a variable value into my href correctly?

Comment: You can use a template filter, like `{% static subpath|add:"/css/animate.css" %}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform the string concatenation with the [**`add`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#add) template filter tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static subpath|add:"/css/animate.css" %}">
```

For example:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> Template('{% load static %}{% static subpath|add:"/css/animate.css" %}').render(Context({'subpath': 'foobar'}))
'/static/foobar/css/animate.css'
```

As you can see the `subpath` variable is associated with the `'foobar'`. So in the `{% static .. %}`, tag we construct with `subpath|add:"/css/animate.css"` a new string `foobar/css/animate.css`. By using the `{% static .. %}` tag, this will be replaced (here, according to default settings), with `/static/foobar/css/animate.css`.